# Derivative of a Function in Modelica

Tags: function, modelica

First, excuse me for not providing a minimal working example, it is that I just can't think of one, really. I'll just give some pieces of code and ask my question "in principle".

I'm doing thermophysical properties calculation with a real gas model (Peng-Robinson) and here I am having problems when translating a model, where I use pressure *p* and specific enthalpy *h* as inputs to calculate all other properties. When it comes to calculating the temperature *T*, it is linked to the enthalpy *h* via an equation called *departure function*, which is itself a function of *T*. In Modelica it looks like this:

```
Dh_real = R_m*T*(Z - 1) + (T*dadT - a)/(sqrt(8)*b)*log((Z + (1 + sqrt(2))*B)/(Z + (1 - sqrt(2))*B));
```

Here `a`, `dadT` and `Z` are also temperature-dependent scalars and partly calculated using matrix operations (`dadT`) or polynomial-root-calculation (`Z`) in functions, `b` and `B` are parameters.

Calculating the enthalpy from an input temperature (in another model) is straightforward and working fine, the solver can solve the *departure function* analytically. The other direction has to be solved numerically and this is, I think, why Dymola gives me this error, when translating.

```
Cannot find differentiation function:
DadT_Unique2([some parameters and T])
with respect to time

Failed to differentiate the equation
dadT = DadT_Unique2([some parameters and T]);

in order to reduce the DAE index.

Failed to reduce the DAE index.
```

Now `DadT` is a function within the model, where I use some simple matrix operations to calculate `dadT` from some parameters and the temperature *T*. Obviously, Dymola is in need of the derivative of some internal `_Unique2`-function.
I couldn't find anything in the specification nor in the web about this. Can I provide a derivative of the functions somehow? I tried the `smoothOrder`-annotation, but without effect. How can I deal with this?

Comment: You can provide a derivative function using the `annotation(derivative=dxyz)`.  Search the Modelica Language Specification for these annotations (inverse might also be interesting) or read more in Michael Tillers online book: http://book.xogeny.com/behavior/functions/func_annos/#derivative

Comment: Thanks for your hints @matth . Am I right, that in the derivative function I'm soupposed to mathematically give the function for the differential of the original function's outputs, so that the compiler can generate derivatives with respect to any variable (and time)? But what if I don't have/can't give a derivative function? For example in my case `Z` is the output of the MSL-function `Modelica.Math.Vectors.Utilities.roots`. How do I get the differential of a root calculation from a third grade polynomial?

Comment: The derivative that you specify is the time derivative, but that one probably calls each partial derivative of your original function. As an example, you can look at the function `density_ph` (and the functions that it calls) of [Modelica.Media.R134a](https://github.com/modelica/Modelica/blob/master/Modelica/Media/R134a.mo) or in the [HelmholtzMedia library](https://github.com/thorade/HelmholtzMedia/tree/master/HelmholtzMedia/Interfaces/PartialHelmholtzMedium). Is your `Z` the compressibility factor?

Comment: @matth yes exactly, that's what it is. I chose to calculate `Z` using the MSL roots-function firstly to be able to access the liquid-phase-Z as well as the vapour-phase-Z and secondly on an earlier development state, I experienced, that the solver automatically picked the wrong solution for `Z` which lead to nonsense results.

Comment: From the Modelica.Media-package I see that the temperature calculation from a given enthalpy is realized with an extra Newton-iteration within a function (`Modelica.Media.R134a.R134a_ph.dtofphOnePhase`). I don't understand, why I would have to implement my own solving routine, when I already have a solver that could do this for me?

Comment: The `Math.Vectors.roots` can only find roots of polynomials and it will return ALL roots, including complex ones. R134a uses the full Helmholtz energy equation of state which is more complicated than just polynomial terms. You can also try to go away from functions/algorithms and use models/equations instead, that will solve some problems but create different ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for your valuable contribution, I'm getting a lot more insight to the under-the-hood-aspects of this issue. I now successfully provided some (dummy) derivatives for the involved functions that I wrote myself but I still have no clue for the `roots`-function. As said, I need the function to acces more than only one of the roots of Z from the third grade Peng-Robinson-polynomial, but can't really give a time-derivative for it. Isn't there a solution/an approach for this? I think using equations and models instead of functions is not really possible here.

Comment: I think you should not provide a derivative of the roots function, but a time derivative of `Z`,  which then calls thermophysical derivatives like `∂Z/∂T|p` and so on, similar to the `density_ph` example. You can express/rewrite derivatives of `Z` with respect to `p` and `h` in terms of derivatives wrt to `T` and `v`: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=3379879976574799663

Comment: OK, but if I want to specify the time derivative of `Z` in terms of other partial derivatives, where can I do this? Adding another equation with a `der()`-declaration will make the equation system structurally singular. And a `derivative`-annotation for the MSL roots-function would expect derivatives of the input (here the polynomial coefficients in a vector), not other partial derivatives. Sorry for potentially not getting you right!

Comment: This will be hard to answer without code. I was assuming that you extend the Media interface with your own implementation. Then nobody would ever call that root finding function directly, but instead one would call some function wrapped around it (that also chooses the correct out of the three roots). Sidenote: If you have only one unknown, you could also consider using `Modelica.Math.Nonlinear.SolveOneNonlinearEquation` to find the root.

Comment: OK here is how I solved this: I managed to give a derivative for Z and all the other functions. For some reasons the single `Failed to reduce the DAE index.`-Error remained though, with no further information what was wrong. So my conclusion was to write my own Newton-solving routine within a function which is working fine and converging pretty fast. Thanks @matth for your guidance.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a full answer, but a list of interesting links that you should read:

- Michael Tiller on `annotation(derivative=dxyz)` and other annotations:
  http://book.xogeny.com/behavior/functions/func_annos/#derivative
- Claytex on numerical Jacobians and flag `Hidden.PrintFailureToDifferentiate`:
  http://www.claytex.com/blog/how-can-i-make-my-models-run-faster/
- Two related questions here on StackOverflow:
  [Dymola solving stationary equation systems for Media-Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253279/dymola-solving-stationary-equation-systems-for-media-model)
  [Two-Phase Modelica Media example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908292/two-phase-modelica-media-example)
- Some related Modelica conference papers:
  https://modelica.org/events/Conference2005/online_proceedings/Session1/Session1c2.pdf
  http://dx.doi.org/10.3384/ecp15118647
  http://dx.doi.org/10.3384/ecp15118653
- Cubic equation of state, generalized form (table 4.2)
  https://books.google.de/books?id=_Op6DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA187
- Solving cubic equations of state:
  http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/aic.690480421
  https://books.google.com/books?id=dd410GGw8wUC&pg=PA48
  https://books.google.com/books?id=1rOA5I6kQ7gC&pg=PA620 (Appendix C)
- Rewriting partial derivatives:
  https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=3379879976574799663